# Can't pass element from array to view

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Trying to -unsuccessfully- pass as separated values into view from this array:

```
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#548 ▼
      +"location": "Guadalajara"
      +"location_id": 34
    }
  ]
}
```

This array comes after a leftjoin query

```
$default_loc = DB::table('users')
                ->leftJoin('locations', 'users.location_id','=','locations.id')
                ->where('users.id',auth()->user()->id)
                ->select('location', 'location_id')
                ->get();
```

If I try to pass this array to the view via `compact('default_loc')` I'd been only able to show the entire array as shown above with `{{ $default_loc }}`, but can't separate it into `$default_loc->location` and `$default_loc->id`.

Thank you all,

Comment: probably since is an array, accessing it as an array, might be a good starting point: `{{ $default_loc[0]->location_id }}`

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$default_loc` is an array, you should treat it as an array, so to access it you need to use the `[]` operator:

```
{{ $default_loc[0]->location_id }}
```

However, if you are sure that only 1 record will be returned, you can use the `first()` method instead of `get()` that will give you directly the object:

```
$default_loc = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('locations', 'users.location_id','=','locations.id')
            ->where('users.id',auth()->user()->id)
            ->select('location', 'location_id')
            ->first();

...
{{ $default_loc->location_id }}
```

Comment: Just for further clarification, `->get()` doesn't return an Array, but rather a Collection: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections. This this a wrapper class for an array, so array access via `[0]` works, but they are distinct enough to be aware of the difference.

Comment: @TimLewis well at first i saw `#items: array` of the output, so i thought it was an array, but yes `get()` returns a Collection

Comment: Haha yeah, that's what you see if you do `dd()` on a Collection :) `dd(collect())`: `Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3289 #items: []}`; you can see the underlying property `#items` is an array

Comment: Thank you. I was not used to return arrays, only strings or integers. I actually wanted to return both elements inside the array so `{{ $default_loc[0]->item}}` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your expected result always 1 result? If yes you can change ->get() for ->first(), then you will have only a single Object.

If not, you need to iterate or access with index in the view:

```
@foreach($default_loc as $loc) 
   {{ $loc->location_id }} - {{ $loc->location }}
@endforeach
```

or

```
{{ $default_loc[INDEX]->location_id }} {{ $default_loc[INDEX]->location }}
```